# Caching Google do not

Tags: google, cache

I'm trying to test the speed of my site with `monitoring-transactionnel.com` I have an error `Vary: Accept-Encoding` with Google but I do not know how to settle the problem.

[image: look]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Google Ads scripts, you can't take control of those scripts nor the way they are served.

You shouldn't worry about them, generally these scripts are really small and Google brings them at Speedlight, and most of the time on your page onload, but if you're still so much concerned about them, you can only remove Google Ads from your page.

Oh also, as I can read here, [load show_ads.js once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842382/load-show-ads-js-once), these scripts are only loaded once, next time they will load from cache.

Comment: Ok I'm not going to take this into account. Too bad because if I did not have this message my site have validated 100%

Comment: Happened the same to me :/ Don't worry about it, it's sth like XHTML/HTML5 validation, normal people visiting your site won't care and won't even know what that is